# Unable to use a variable in a sh block

Tags: jenkins, syntax, sh, variable-assignment, jenkins-pipeline

Why do I get the following error:

> ++ cat package.json
>   ++ jq .version
>   + TAG = '"0.0.5"' /****/script.sh:
>   line 12: TAG: command not found

When running the below in a Jenkinsfile:

```
sh '''
    ...
    ...
    TAG = \$(cat package.json | jq '.version')
    git tag -a v${TAG} -m "New release: ${TAG}"
'''
```

Comment: The shell syntax to set a variable is `<var>=<value>` with no space around the `=` sign.

Comment: Please take a look: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As was mentioned in the comments, the problem was with the spaces before and after `=`. Additionally, I added escaping in the second line so it'll display as `v0.0.6` and not `v"0.0.6"`.

```
sh '''
    ...
    ...
    TAG=\$(jq -r '.version' package.json)
    git tag -a "v${TAG}" -m "New release: ${TAG}"
'''
```